# Re-instantiating objects without losing previous

Tags: java

I'm not too sure about how I should go about solving this problem for an assignment I have.

I'm being asked to keep track of multiple flights, they're all stored in one file, each line represents a various aspect of each flight. I'm asked to keep track of every flight by its flight number in an ordered list.

Right now I'm just trying to test my code out without any of the fileIO. Here's what I have right now,

```
OrderedList flights = new OrderedList();

Flight flight = new Flight();
flight.setFlightNumber(678);
flights.add(flight);

flights.printList();
```

This code works fine, however when I will do my fileIO I will need to re instantiate the variable to another flight like so,

```
....
flight = new Flight();
flight.setFlightNumber(876);
flights.add(flight);

flights.printList();
```

I think that what's happening here is the pointer to the old flight isn't being found? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to work around this?

EDIT: Some more information, when compiled I get a run time error of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Flight cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

The error is thrown in my OrderedList class one the add methods line of,

```
while(current != null && (newFlight.getFlightNumber() > (Integer)current.getData())) {
```

Here's a screenshot of the debugger,

[image: Debugger]

Comment: You may need to tell us more details about how your code isn't working. I myself am lost.

Comment: Ah sorry, I will edit the post in a second with the errors thrown.

Comment: ... unless Xi Han's answer is adequate that is.

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: `(Integer)current.getData()` what is `current` here?

Comment: @immibis current is set to the head of the orderedList, which for the first one is null. If you want I can add in all of the code for that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Flight cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

This means you tried to cast a Flight to an Integer. Flights are not Integers, so you just can't do that.

If it happened on this line:

```
while(current != null && (newFlight.getFlightNumber() > (Integer)current.getData())) {
```

then the thing you're casting is the result of `current.getData()`. So `current.getData()` returned a Flight, and you tried to cast it to an Integer. I'm guessing you actually meant something like this:

```
while(current != null && (newFlight.getFlightNumber() > ((Flight)current.getData()).getFlightNumber())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you will not lose previous flights records because the `OrderedList` will keep the reference of those records.

Comment: What type does `getData()` return?

Comment: public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

Comment: You may want to use `((Flight)(current.getData()).getFlightNumber()`

Comment: I've tried that, it throws an error, "Cannot resolve method getFlightNumber()"